# Using python virtualenv in mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am learning Django (using version 1.4.5, bitnami stack) and Python (2.7.3) and trying to use virtualenv (version 1.8.4) for the first time. I have already installed virtualenv using pip and it seemed to install fine. However, when I try to create a new virtualenv environment, I seem to run into problems. Here's the errors I'm getting:

Attempt 1:

```
$ python virtualenv.py ENV
/Applications/djangostack-1.4.5-0/python/bin/.python2.7.bin: can't open file 'virtualenv.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

Attempt 2:

```
$ virtualenv venv --distribute
dyld: Library not loaded: /bitnami/djangostack-osx-x64/output/python/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/djangostack-1.4.5-0/python/bin/.python2.7.bin
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
```

I searched for virtualenv.py and found that it is located at: 
/Applications/djangostack-1.4.5-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Attempt 3: I can cd to this folder from the command line and run the following command to create a new environment in the myproject_dir folder:

```
$ python virtualenv.py myproject_dir
```

Unlike Attempts 1 and 2, Attempt 3 actually seems to work, but it is not optimal. So, my conclusion is that somehow for the commands in Attempts 1 and 2, the system is looking in the wrong place. My sense is that a setting needs to be changed somewhere to point to the correct location of the virtualenv.py file, but I'm not sure where to look and how to actually make the changes? I've looked at other explanations on this site and Google, but still am not sure whether my diagnosis of the problem is correct and how to actually fix the problem.

Comment: my 2 cent guess: you are using the bitnami stack and it includes the python for you. Your python path is changed into the bitnami folder, instead of the normal folder of Mac OS; therefore, the virtualenv cannot lookup the old settings to load. I think you just need to install django and all the related stuffs manually and things will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Attempt one, don't do that, do this:

```
virtualenv ENV
```

attempt two indicates that you have your python paths muddled up as @Thai Trans says. I would make sure that you're calling the correct python from virtualenv

```
virtualenv -p /path/to/bitnami/python ENV
```

and not worry about the `--distribute` flag until you've got your regular `virtualenv` working.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you're right that the paths are the problem. I tried typing ". apache2/bin/envvars" on the command line from the django root folder and it seems to fix the problem for the duration of the session. I'm going to use this as an interim solution until I have a chance to reinstall python, etc.